# Unable to find observer in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, helper, observer-pattern, observers

I tried to register my `ObserverHelper` in the `AppServiceProvider` as below, but I am getting the following error.

> Unable to find observer: App\Helpers\App\Observers\FileLogObserver

**AppServiceProvider.php**

```
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Helpers\ObserverHelper;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
    }

    public function boot()
    {
        ObserverHelper::register();
    }
}
```

**ObserverHelper.php**

```
namespace App\Helpers;

class ObserverHelper
{
    protected static $observers = [
        'App\Models\FileLogs' => App\Observers\FileLogObserver::class,
    ];

    public static function register()
    {
        foreach (self::$observers as $model => $observer) {
            $model::observe($observer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a typo, add `\ ` before `App\Observers\FileLogObserver::class` or use `use App\Observers\FileLogObserver;` at the start of file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a `\` (backslash that references the global namespace) in front of the `App\Observers\FileLogObserver::class`, or import that class.

**With backslash (reference global namespace):**

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

class ObserverHelper
{
    protected static $observers = [
        'App\Models\FileLogs' => \App\Observers\FileLogObserver::class,
    ];

    public static function register()
    {
        foreach(self::$observers as $model => $observer) {
            $model::observe($observer);
        }
    }
}
```

**or with import:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

use App\Observers\FileLogObserver;

class ObserverHelper
{
    protected static $observers = [
        'App\Models\FileLogs' => FileLogObserver::class,
    ];

    public static function register()
    {
        foreach(self::$observers as $model => $observer) {
            $model::observe($observer);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** Even though your code is a valid solution, consider creating a separate provider for defining observers (`ObserverServiceProvider` for example).